# What is a TRACON?

Tags: air-traffic-control, usa, faa

- What is a TRACON or Terminal Control?
- When do pilots need to be helped by a TRACON?
- Where is it usually located and what is the difference between TRACON, En Route and Tower?

Comment: For smaller planes that do not get too high, we are often handed off from Tower, to Approach (which would be a TRACON facility it seems) to Approach to Approach, and eventually back to a Tower.  If between TRACONs, and high enough up, we might get handed to a Center for part of the route.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

***What is a TRACON (Terminal Radar Approach CONtrol)?***

A TRACON is a term used in the US for what is elsewhere known as the *[Terminal Control](http://www.airportfreak.yolasite.com/airport-control.php)* (ICAO terminology), the control in charge of operations around one or more large airports. It doesn't manage ATC at airports, which is provided by TOWERs. TRACON is therefore an intermediate step used for:

- Climbing departing flights received from TOWERs and handing them over to ARTCC.
- Descending cruising flights received from ARTCC and handing them over to airfield TOWERs

[image]
<sup>([Source](http://www.natca.org/))</sup>

FAA describes a TRACON [like this](https://www.faa.gov/news/fact_sheets/news_story.cfm?contentkey=4009):

> TRACON controllers generally handle within a 30- to 50-mile radius of
> an airport and up to 10 000 feet, as well as aircraft flying over that
> airspace. They are responsible for the safe separation of aircraft
> flying in the busy areas surrounding airports.

***When do pilots need to be helped by a TRACON?***

Pilots are directed to a TRACON center either by the Tower controller (for departures), or the ARTCC controller (for descents and transits). The services are delivered by radio from radar data. They typically encompass controlling aircraft during standard approach (STAR) and standard departures (SID). TRACON frequencies are mentioned on instrument plates as *Approach* (APP CON) and *Departure* (DEP CON), e.g. for Las Vegas ([source](https://skyvector.com/airport/LAS/Mc-Carran-International-Airport)):

[image: Approach control frequency on STAR]

Typical service provided to a descending aircraft ([source](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19900001525/downloads/19900001525.pdf)):

> Typically, arrival traffic is handed off from the ARTCC to the TRACON
> air space at designated points, called feeder gates, about 30n.mi.
> from the airport and 10,000 to 15,000ft above ground level. Some
> airports utilize as many as four or five such gates or corner posts
> which approximately form a rectangle with the airport at the center
> [...]   Both feeder and final controllers attempt to keep aircraft on
> a fastest or shortest path to the runway. They often utilize speed
> changes, altitude changes, and path stretching to ensure proper
> spacing.

Similarly, climbing aircraft are directed via preferential departure routes towards the en-route airway, before being handed to Air Route Traffic Control Center (ARTCC).

Controllers mostly use the Automated Radar Terminal System (ARTS) or the Standard Terminal Automation Replacement System (STARS) systems to track aircraft:

[image]
<sup>Philadelphia TRACON ([source](http://wiki.vzdc.org/tiki-index.php?page=Introduction+to+Radar))</sup>

As emphasized by @TomMcW in his comment, smaller airfields don't have an associated TRACON, the approaches and departures are in this case directly managed by controllers at the airfield tower.

---

***Where are TRACON usually located?***

TRACON *premises* by themselves can be located anywhere. Controllers work on radar screens, in the half-light, they don't have a view of the outdoor. Basement rooms are usual.

[image]
<sup>Potomac consolidated TRACON, operation room ([source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_traffic_control#Approach_and_terminal_control))</sup>

Depending on the country they may be located close to major airports, within the area they control, preferably co-located with towers.

TRACON *controlled areas* are located around major airports.

- In the US: [FAA - Terminal Radar Approach Control Facilities](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/air_traffic_services/tracon/)
- In Europe (TCC): See [Can multiple airfields be in the same airspace?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11548/can-multiple-airfields-be-in-the-same-airspace)

[From FAA](https://www.faa.gov/news/fact_sheets/news_story.cfm?contentkey=4009) (where are TRACONs located?)

> Some TRACONs are located on airport property and some are not, but
> their locations have no effect on TRACON controllers’ ability to
> control aircraft, or on the capacity or capabilities of any airport.
> This is because TRACON controllers rely on radar displays and radio to
> separate aircraft, unlike tower controllers who control landings and
> takeoffs visually. In fact, TRACONs do not have windows — a darker
> environment makes it easier for controllers to see the radar screens.

The article mentions cases like [N90 TRACON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_TRACON): It controls traffic from/to major airports in NY area (La Guardia, JFK, Newark Liberty), but is located on Long Island, a location remote from these airports.

FAA arguments for tower and TRACON co-location include savings and easier 24/7 uninterrupted operations.

---

***What is the difference between TRACON, En Route and Tower?***

Taking the US ATC system only into account for this discussion. The difference should have been clarified above: Towers handle airport operations, ARTCCs/En-route handle cruise phase, and TRACONs handle climbing and descending aircraft, as well as aircraft transiting between ARTCCs in their controlled areas. Here are some details about Towers and ARTCCs.

1/ **Airport operations** are controlled by controllers in the *tower*. They need a view on the runways and other location of the airport.

[image]
<sup>Tower at Nice / Côte d'Azur airport ([LFMN](https://www.iao-project.eu/wp/?page_id=194))</sup>

Radar techniques are used for tracking aircraft on the ground (ASDE-X) and informations from short range radars can feed various displays, of which the [D/BRITE](https://www.airport-data.com/airport/photo/007337.html) (Digital Bright Radar Indicator Tower Equipment), and more modern Barco.

Takeoff and landing clearances are delivered after visual check of the runway status.

From [Nasa's page](http://virtualskies.arc.nasa.gov/atm/4.html):

> Control towers were established to provide for a safe, orderly, and
> expeditious flow of air traffic at an airport and in its vicinity.
> There are four major controller classifications at control towers:
>
> - Flight Data Controller
> - Clearance Delivery Controller
> - Ground Controller
> - Local Controller.

[image]
<sup>Inside an air traffic control tower ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/3gx0ng/inside_an_air_traffic_control_tower/))</sup>

2/ **Enroute traffic** is controlled by *Air Route Traffic Control Center* (ARTCC)

[image]
<sup>Typical sector radar team ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/40axat/people_who_work_for_airlines_what_are_secrets))</sup>

From [Nasa's page](http://virtualskies.arc.nasa.gov/atm/6.html):

> ARTCCs, usually referred to as "Centers," are established primarily to
> provide Air Traffic Service to aircraft operating on IFR flight plans
> within the controlled airspace, and principally during the en route
> phase of flight.
>
> There are 21 Air Route Traffic Control Centers (ARTCC) in the United
> States.

[image]
<sup>US ARTCC boundaries ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/aviation/comments/3674wr/us_air_traffic_control_zones/))</sup>

> Any aircraft operating under Instrument Flight Rules (IFR) within the
> confines of an ARTCC's airspace is controlled by air traffic
> controllers at the Center. This includes all sorts of different types
> of aircraft: privately owned single engine aircraft, commuter
> airlines, military jets and commercial airlines.

ARTCC manages flights between TRACON airspaces, while they are cruising at high altitude.

(You can listen to ARTCC traffic at [LiveATC.net](https://www.liveatc.net/feedindex.php?type=us-artcc))

---

Read more:

- [Air traffic control](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_traffic_control)
- [New York TRACON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_TRACON)
- [TRACON 2012](http://www.atcsuite.com/index_tracon.html), the game
- [Co-Located TRACONS](http://www.faa.gov/news/fact_sheets/news_story.cfm?contentkey=4009) (FAA)
- [ATC Positions and Functions](http://old.vatusa.net/training/tiki-index.php?page=atc_positions_and_functions) (VATUSA, ATC simulation)

Comment: I was half way through an answer for this but yours is so thorough I don't need to finish it. +1. Only thing I might add is that TRACON facilities are around busy airspace. Smaller airports in the US have approach and departure controllers at the ATCT. I was surprised that the class B airport where I live (MCI) doesn't have a TRACON even though there's an ARTCC in town.

Comment: "A TRACON is the name in the US for what is also known in other countries as the Terminal Control Center, the control in charge of operations close to one or more large airports (but not on the airports themselves)." - Are TRACONs in the US *sometimes* located on the airports themselves? I was once inside the Grand Rapids ATC tower, and there was an ATC room directly below the "room with the big windows". My understanding was that the upper room was Grand Rapids Tower and the lower room was TRACON (Grand Rapids Approach and Grand Rapids Departure).

Comment: @TannerSwett: I don't know for Grand Rapids, but that's the idea, it's usual. For LFPG (De Gaulle), see fig 73 page 107 of [this document](http://masig.ensg.eu/PDF/CDG.pdf) in French. The room is below one of the towers. When I write "not on the airports themselves" I mean TRACON don't control aircraft on the airports, but they can be (and usually are) located at one major airport.

Comment: Ah, I see. I wasn't paying attention when I read the sentence; I thought it was saying that the *facilities themselves* are "not on the airports themselves", but now I see that I was reading it wrong.

Comment: How is a TRACON depicted for an airport on sectional charts?

Comment: @TheStoryCoder: The TRACON service is reachable thru the allocated frequency. The frequency may be different between sectors / airports / runways and whether the aircraft is climbing or descending, and cannot be shown on sectional charts. Instead it appears on the relevant IFR plate (e.g. on SID and STAR they appear respectively as "DEP CON" and "APP CON", [examples](https://laartcc.org/airport/KLAS); the location of the facility itself is irrelevant to navigation and not shown).

Comment: @TerranSwett Most TRACONs are “up/down” facilities, which means they are in the same building as a tower and may even share staff. Larger ones will be in their own building but still usually on airport property. This contrasts with ARTCCs, which tend to be miles away from any airport.

Comment: @TomMcW: the TRACON is the facility or portion of the facility responsible for radar guidance, like StephenS said; an up/down like MCI contains both a tower and a TRACON. And general note: "TRACON" is the FAA term for this type of facility. The military calls it a "RAPCON," "RATCF," or "ARAC" (USA), but in all cases the services provided are the same.

Comment: @TheStoryCoder no, see [my answer here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/84039/54557) for the best you're likely to get.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there needs to be a distinction between the IFR facility and the Tower. Control towers in the US control runways and surface movement areas, they do not "control" airspace. They do sequence aircraft in the local traffic area but that is a topic for another discussion. TRACONS/RAPCONS are IFR facilities and can issue IFR routes/clearances in the air.

TRACONS typically control airspace around busy airports from the ground up to 15,000ft and about 30 miles around including all airports therein. ARTCC's (Centers or Area control Facilities) cover EVERYTHING else. They provide IFR service from the surface up to the top of controlled airspace in the vast majority of the continental US. There are plenty of smallish airports (especially out west) that have towers without an overlying TRACON. In those areas, the ARTCC is the next layer providing arrival/departure separation, sometimes without radar.

Answer (score 0):

I've been a Professional Airway System Specialist for 29 years. Some of the information in the above article is either misleading or downright incorrect.
Air Traffic Control Towers large enough to require a nearby or co-located TRACON include Digital BRITE Radar displays overhead in the towers.
In my day they were fed by Automated Radar IIA and IIIA systems that were in turn fed by short range (60 mile radars).
Today the Standard Terminal Automation Replacement System (STARS) has replaced the ARTS systems but STARS Automated Radar is still either microwaved to the larger towers or sent via advanced telecommunications.
That information IS NOT used for ground separation it is used by tower controllers to control traffic IN THE AIR that they cannot see which is the majority of the traffic that they control.

Comment: Welcome! With your experience, I'm sure you'll be able to help out with a lot of good answers!! Your answer would probably be better suited as comments on the specific answers, but you don't have the rep to do that yet. Could you please [edit] your answer to include specific quotes from the other answers that you believe to be incorrect? Someone will help you with the formatting if it doesn't come out all that well at first. Also, take a couple of minutes to take the [tour] and read the [help] to get the feel for how things work at [Aviation.se] since it's a bit different than other forums.

Comment: Following is the statement I found to be incorrect:

Comment: I think your Enter key finger got a little trigger happy, care to try again?  :) Also, statements like "the first answer" or "the answer above" are totally irrelevant at any of the StackExchange sites - There are 3 different ways of sorting answers and each user can choose his own way, and, if you and I both select "votes" that will still change over time as different answers are voted on. Best to at least reference the answer's author.

Comment: I encourage you to make a complementary answer with details. DBRITE (Digital Bright Radar Indicator Tower Equipment) are the displays for data/images coming from the STARS/ARTS systems ([example](http://www.ky4ky.com/archives/pa0103.htm)).