# Where can I obtain a .KML file for a TRACON’s area of responsibility?

Tags: air-traffic-control, aeronautical-charts, tracon

I want an overlay on my moving map for the radar service areas of a TRACON facility.  Are there any sites that host this for free?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44593/62), although no accepted answer

Comment: SE GIS and/or Open Data may be of assistance.

Comment: As I don't like double posting, you might want to have a look to my [answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/86982/878) on the same question that @Pondlife linked. Please note though that the provided format is AIXM, not KML

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis, AIXM is extension of GML and converting that to KML should be fairly easy (selecting which polygons to extract will be the harder part).